# How to get the Search REST API sort to not be case sensitive?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, search, rest

I am using the Search REST API to get a list of users, and am trying to sort the results by last name. However, the sort seems to be case sensitive. Is there a way to change the way items are sorted?

REST query:

```
http://server/_api/search/query?querytext='lastname:d*'&sourceid='B09A7990-05EA-4AF9-81EF-EDFAB16C4E31'&sortlist='lastname:ascending'&rowlimit=200&selectproperties='accountname,lastname,firstname'&trimduplicates=false
```

partial results:

1. Davidson
2. DeSoto
3. Dean
4. Demple

How do I adjust the REST query so that Dean comes before DeSoto? (or, is some language rule in play that I'm not aware of?)

Comment: Have you tried odata `orderby`? `&$orderby=lastname`

Comment: The OData order by statement seems to have no affect.